# Proceeding in Movieclip After Animation Finishes AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, transition, movieclip

I have a Movieclip on my stage which contains two buttons: Back and Next. Also on the timeline, I have another Movieclip which contains an animation. After the next button is clicked, I'd like to have the animation transition into the next animation without jumping. So, is there any way I can listen for the animation to be finished so that I can time the transitions seamlessly?

Here is the code for my Next and Back buttons (which are movieclip buttons which is why there is all of the extra code) which just switch between frames as of now:

```
//NEXT BUTTON
nextBtn.buttonMode = true; 

nextBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, nextBtnOver);
nextBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, nextBtnOut);
nextBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, nextBtnDown);
nextBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, nextBtnUp);

function nextBtnOver(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    nextBtn.gotoAndPlay("over");
}

function nextBtnOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
nextBtn.gotoAndPlay(9- (nextBtn.currentFrame-1));
}

function nextBtnDown (e:MouseEvent):void
{
nextBtn.gotoAndPlay("down");
}

function nextBtnUp (e:MouseEvent):void
{
    nextBtn.gotoAndPlay(5);
    MovieClip(root).nextFrame();
}

//BACK BUTTON
backBtn.buttonMode = true; 

backBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, backBtnOver);
backBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, backBtnOut);
backBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, backBtnDown);
backBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, backBtnUp);

function backBtnOver(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    backBtn.gotoAndPlay("over");
}

function backBtnOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    backBtn.gotoAndPlay(9- (backBtn.currentFrame-1));
}

function backBtnDown (e:MouseEvent):void
{
    backBtn.gotoAndPlay("down");
}

function backBtnUp (e:MouseEvent):void
{
    backBtn.gotoAndPlay(5);
    MovieClip(root).prevFrame();
}
```

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you want, do you mean adding an enter frame event and checking for the MovieClip to reach its `currentFrame`?

Comment: I'd like to have it not matter when you hit the next button, because I want the animation on the timeline to finish before the effect of the next button works, if that makes sense. I have an animation timed, so that if it finishes it's animation it will transition seamlessly, otherwise it will jump - which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Why don't you just check your animations currentFrame in the `nextBtnUp()`. That is `if ( animation.currentFrame == animation.totalFrames )` then you can do the `nextFrame()` etc.

Comment: @BennettYeates I tried this, and it works - except in order for it to advance to the next point you have to click the next button at exactly the right frame. I'd like to make it so you can click it at any point in the Movieclip, and it will play the remainder of the Movieclip before proceeding to the next frame. Here's my code for what I've added: function nextBtnUp (e:MouseEvent):void { nextBtn.gotoAndPlay(5); if (MovieClip(root).animationTest.currentFrame == MovieClip(root).animationTest.totalFrames) MovieClip(root).nextFrame(); } Thank you for the help so far

Answer (score 0):

If your animations are timelined, call an **animationComplete** function in the last frame of your animation movieClip.  This function would live at the same scope as your posted code above, so you just have to be able to path to it properly from within the animation clip.  For instance, if the code is one level outside the animation movieClip (the mc's parent) then you might call this.parent.animationComplete(), which would contain the code you want to execute when the animation finishes.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment,

```
I tried this, and it works - except in order for
it to advance to the next point you have
to click the next button at exactly the right frame.
I'd like to make it so you can click it at any point in the Movieclip, and it
will play the remainder of the Movieclip before proceeding
to the next frame. Here's my code for what I've added: function
nextBtnUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
nextBtn.gotoAndPlay(5); if (MovieClip(root).animationTest.currentFrame ==
MovieClip(root).animationTest.totalFrames) MovieClip(root).nextFrame();
}
Thank you for the help so far
```

You have it most of it figured out, so to finish can add `stop()` in the code at the last frame of your MovieClips, or you can do this (the more complex version):

```
yourClip.yourFirstClip.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, stopAtLastFrame);
yourClip.yourSecondClip.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, stopAtLastFrame);
function stopAtLastFrame(e:Event):void
{
    if(e.currentTarget.currentFrame === e.currentTarget.totalFrames)
    //                              ^Note that no conversion is being made, so you can have 3 equal signs
    {
        e.currentTarget.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if I add a stop(); at the last frame, the animation stops there. I'd like to have the animation constantly be looping until the user hits the next button, and only then does it wait for the animation to finish before it proceeds to it's next state. Right now, I just have one large movieclip, and a gotoAndPlay(1); command in the middle of the timeline, so it it loops halfway through. If I could have a command that waits until the animation finishes, then sends the user to the frame AFTER the gotoAndPlay() command, it would be preferable. Thank you.

Comment: @Michael_McAfee Look at [Booleans](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Boolean.html)